# Web pages with charset UTF-8 not decoded properly

Tags: 14.04, firefox

Some web pages encoded in UTF-8 are not displayed properly. The Swedish letters
Å Ä Ö are replaced with special characters like ¥ and   ¶ but at the same time there are other pages that are displayed just fine.

I don't know if it have something to do with my locale settings or not or maybe a required package that I may miss?

Because I'm just one in reputation I cannot post images, therefore I can only show you my locale settings for now:

```
LANG=sv_SE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=sv
LC_CTYPE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="sv_SE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Upload on imgur and add a link. We can convert it to embedded images.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this webpage : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale
Maybe it will help you. What exactly is your browser.